# dropdown value stores data upto space only

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I have two dropdowns in my form.
1)Brand Name of car
2)Model name in which data is going to be retrieved from database on the basis of brand name selected.
so I have taken a div tag and appended that second dropdown.The data in dropdown is displayed properly but the problem is in storing the data selected from the second dropdown, It stores the model name upto the space only.length in the database for that field is also taken properly.
eg- if the model name is "series 1" than it will store only series.

Php page of second dropdown:

```
<?php

$brand = $_GET['brand'];
include('connection.php');
$sql = "select * from modelname where Brand_Name='" . $brand . "'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$html = "";
$html = '<select name="model">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $html.='<option value=' . $row['M_Name'] . '>' . $row['M_Name'] .  '</option>';
    }
$html.='</select>';
echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

because you are not quoting your attributes.

```
value=hello world
```

is seen as

```
value="hello" world
```

Add the missing quotes.